# How do I add labels to tcalendarview in delphi

Tags: delphi, calendar

I have been looking for a calendar component that will allow me to add text/labels to the day cells, but haven't been able to do so yet.

In lieu of that, I am trying to update a custom calendar component.  this component was developed using the code from vcl.samples.calendar (so, like, windows 16), and is grid based.

I want to update it to using a current calendar (vcl.winXCalendars).
It's required that it takes and displays a series of text labels (exactly 4), with fonts, color, visible/not visible and right aligned text, in the day cells.

The original code cloned the vcl.samples.calendar (instead of inheriting), then used the draw events to show the values for the day from an element array of the values. The values, in this case, is a number of hours worked for the day, broken into 3 classifications and a total (no start/end times, which is why a scheduler wouldn't work).

I am having a bit of an issue tracking down 'where' to put this code in place in a calendar inherited from tCalendar view.  (note: NOT a component writer, though I seem to be dabbling in it more and more these days)

Anyone have any idea how to do this? Or know of a calendar component that will allow it?

Comment: `TCalendar` component from `vcl.samples.calendar` is just a wrapper for windows calendar. This is why it visual matches the calendar visual of the Windows version on which your application is executed. `TCalendarView` is designed in order to match the look of Windows 10 calendar but is not dependent of tho operating system your application is ran on.  I'm guessing you would have better chance in modifying the `TCalendarView` as it is rendered by your application and not windows itself. So I suggest you try to study its code. It is based on several classes each representing separate item of it

Comment: @Silver Please let me disagree. The `Vcl.Samples.Calendar.TCalendar` inherits from `vcl.grids.TCustomGrid` which inherits from `Vcl.Controls.TCustomControl`. It is far from "just a wrapper for windows calendar". Perhaps you were thinking about the `TMonthCalender`, but that is a different story, and doesn't fit askers task anyway.

Comment: @Connie, it is correct that the out-of-box visual appearance of `vcl.samples.calendar` is not very impressing. But OTOH, it is open for modification as you wish, in the `OnDrawCell` event. Is it correct that your current code already shows the texts and that you are just looking for an upgrade in the appearance? What exactly would such an upgrade include?

Comment: @Tom yes, exactly.  Company wants application to stop looking like it was written in the 90's.  I've implemented devexpress grids, but their scheduler needs a start/end time, so I'm still looking for other solutions.  It is perferred that it looks like the calendar under windows 10 in the pallette, but at least like the one under win32

Comment: @Tom  by 'updating' I mean the month/year picker across the top, as well as having the previous/next months dates showing in the calendar.